# Read values from a drop down list

Tags: jss

New to SitecoreJSS and Angular.

> Using Sitecore 9.0.1 and SitecoreJSS 11.0 (Angular)

Created field - "HeadingBackgroundColor" type **Droplist** with data source pointing to different folder (I can directly use ColorPicker or Single line text and pass HEX color there. But our client wants the  DropDown list)
[image: Template filed]

Data source folder:
[image]

On the Item level I choose Green color (from drop down list):
[image]

In the back end code (angular) I am able to read the Dropdown list data (Which is ***Green***)

.html

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgColor}">Heading</div>
```

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.bgColor = getFieldValue<any>(this.rendering, 'HeadingBackgroundColor');
}
```

Browser Console: (it's passing item name)

```
<div style="background-color:Green;">>Heading</div>
```

Is there way to read the hex color (#969300) instead of passing Item name ***Green***.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Read it from the html element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Answer (score 1):

Change data type of "HeadingBackgroundColor" to "DropLink". With this change your layout service will return all fields of the item selected in the DropLink [HeadingBackgroundColor] field.

```
You might be able to find the color code in the object 
"HeadingBackgroundColor":{"id":"00000000","url":"/Green","fields":{"colorcode":{"value":"#969300"}}}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the data type to DropLink and in the HTML it's not reading Droplink data. FYI - I am not using any GraphQL.

Comment: Can you please post your layout service output.? it should respond the items referred in drop link field.

Comment: could you please tell me how I can review the output without using GraphQL query?

Comment: https://{domain-name}/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={9999-9999-99999-9999999}
replace domain name and api key with your domaina name and api key

Comment: Thank you. "HeadingBackgroundColor2":{"id":"85efb2f5-8ade-4bb2-94b2-fa2063dce3bf","url":"/common-data/background-color-selection/bg-blue","fields":{"BackgroundColorHex":{"value":"#003e5f"}}}}}. I am able to see the values, but how I am going to read the value in (.ts) file ?

Comment: just try HeadingBackgroundColor2.fields.BackgroundColorHex          you might be able to get the value by navigating through your new field HeadingBackgroundColor2 object..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inline styling, you can use css class attribute.

Now  Droplist item names will be the css classes.

.Green{background-color: #969300;}

Inside the div 
`<div class={{bgColor}}>Heading</div>`

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I already tried this. But the only draw back on this is - we can't change/add colors dynamically. If we want to add new color it's going to be code change/deployment.